# need help with Laplace transform of $t^2 \cos(\omega t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I looked up the Laplace transform table on [tutorial.math.lamar.edu](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx), and it says that $$t^n f(t) = (-1)^n F^n(s)$$

In my head that should equal

$$-1^2 (s/s^2 + \omega^2)^2$$

I put the question into Symbolab to check myself and it says that the answer is
$$\frac{-(2s(-s^2+3\omega^2)}{(s^2+\omega^2)^3}$$

According to symbolab you have to take the derivative of the $(\mathcal{L}f)(s)$.Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: nevermind. I looked up some other Laplace transform tables and there is supposed to be a d/d(s) in there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: Please: Don't write $-1^2$ when you mean $(-1)^2.$ In standard usage, $-1^2$ means $-(1^2),$ and that is equal to $-1,$ and $(-1)^2$ is $+1. \qquad$

Comment: The page to which you link says that the Laplace transform of $t^n f(t)$ is $(-1)^n F^{(n)}(s),$ not that it is $(-1)^n F^n(s).$ And $F^{(n)}(s)$ is the $n$th derivative of $F$ evaluated at $s.$ So $F^{(2)}(s) = F''(s). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you stated we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) that:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[x^\text{n}\cdot\text{f}\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{d}^\text{n}}{\text{ds}^\text{n}}\left(\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{f}\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\right)\tag1$$

And we also [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) that:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\cos\left(\omega x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{s}}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\tag2$$

So, for your problem we get:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[x^2\cos\left(\omega x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\left(-1\right)^2\cdot\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\text{s}^2}\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\right)=\frac{2\text{s}\left(\text{s}^2-3\omega^2\right)}{\left(\text{s}^2+\omega^2\right)^3}\tag3$$